# php fetch date column from database

Tags: php, mysql, date, web

```
SELECT c.enddate FROM cohort c ORDER BY c.enddate DESC LIMIT 1
```

I have a sql query above, it works in database, the result select a date like: '**2018-07-18**'

I try to use while loop with mysqli_fetch_row in php to fetch this date, but the result will only fetch:
**2018**

How can I get the whole date?

```
if ($runquery = $conn->query($result_validation))
{
    //get the enddate from the last cohort
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($runquery))
    {
        $lastDate = $row[0];
    }
}
```

`$row[0]` only display first number: 2018.

Comment: Can you please post the php code as well? It seems that's where the issue may lie.

Comment: Are you outputting the result in the loop or just trying to access after?

Comment: try adding DATE ,  SELECT DATE(c.enddate) FROM cohort c ORDER BY DATE(c.enddate) DESC LIMIT 1, if you can add your loop code here

Comment: @bdalina Put your code in comments to the answer so that the OP can mark the answer as accepted if your code works.

Answer (score 1):

Adding DATE() function in the column will convert it to a valid date format like for the example below!

```
SELECT DATE(c.enddate) FROM cohort c ORDER BY DATE(c.enddate) DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thanks for all of your answers, yes, simply add DATE() works

Answer (score 1):

Try `SELECT DATE(c.enddate) FROM cohort c ORDER BY c.enddate DESC LIMIT 1`,

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(c.enddate,"%Y-%m-%d") FROM cohort c ORDER BY c.enddate DESC LIMIT 1
```

The `DATE_FORMAT()` function formats a date as specified by a format mask.